# How do I get Woocommerce product variation name and variation description in a WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I get the product variations each as their own button with below code that I have pieced together. Echo $product->name outputs something like "Product - variation" but I need "**Variation** price". Price would be entered in description field in the dashboard. I have gone through several related questions and answers but I'm not skilled enough to apply the solutions to my code so help would be appreciated!

```
    <?php
    $params = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'product_variation', 'order' => 'ASC');
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
    ?>
    <?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
      <form class="cart" action="<?php the_permalink() ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr($product->id); ?>">
          <button <?php post_class('button') ?> type="submit"><strong><?php echo $product->name ?> </strong></button>
      </form>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else:  ?>
    <div>
          <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so soon after posting I came up with a working solution. With this code I get the price straight from the variation price field, not from the description field as I mentioned in my question.

```
<?php
    $params = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'product_variation', 'order' => 'ASC');
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
    global $product;
    ?>
    <?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
      <form class="cart" action="<?php the_permalink() ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr($product->id); ?>">
          <button <?php post_class('button') ?> type="submit"><strong><?php echo implode("", $product->get_variation_attributes()); ?> </strong><span style="display: inline-block"><?php echo $product->get_price(); ?></span></button>
      </form>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else:  ?>
    <div>
          <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```